# jQRangeSlider custom scales

Tags: jquery-plugins

Don't know if this is possible but I'm trying to create custom scales for my jQrangeSlider but not using increments, the way shown [here](http://ghusse.github.io/jQRangeSlider/options.html#scalesOption). 
I have a date range slider, ranging from 3+ yrs ago till todays date, and I need to have 2 scales (being set dynamically, from a DB) inside the ranges.

```
The Docs say:
The function first(min, max) [optional]

Must return the ruler first value.
It gives you a way to make the ruler start after the slider minimum. 
By default, this method returns the slider minimum value.
```

I'm assuming  I need this for the first scale / tick. My issue is getting it to its proper spot in the range. Meaning, if the function always return the first value, then do I need to add *'n'* days (using a dateRangeSlider) to the value?.... still trying to wrap my head around it...Thanks

Ex. 03/12/2013 and  10/20/2013.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can customize ticks in scales, using javascript callbacks. So basically, you can do whatever you want.

Just customize these functions to make them return what you need, depending on what you get from the DB.

You can try something like that:

```
var yourFirstValue = new Date(2013, 2, 13),
    yourSecondValue = new Date(2013, 9, 20);

var scaleConfiguration = {
  first: function(val){ return yourFirstValue; },
  next: function(val){ return yourSecondValue; },
  stop: function(val){ return val === yourSecondValue; }
};
```

Comment: Edited, to be more specific